# What is return type statement in this code

Tags: android, sdk

What should I put to remove the error here?

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString)  {
            currentURL = urlNewString;
        }//here is error for return type
});
```

Comment: Explain your question and post all the code

Answer (score 0):

From [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) set return type as True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

```
     @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString)  
     {
        currentURL = urlNewString;
        return true;
        //return true load with system-default-browser or other browsers, false with your webView

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return `true` if you want to override loading URI or `false` instead.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString)  {
    currentURL = urlNewString;
    return true; //or false
}
```